# when i upload file in laravel then we face this issue "Path cannot be empty" in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9, laravel-10

I want to save image file in the storage folder but when I insert a file in my form and I click on the button, it displays me the error "Path cannot be empty".

Path cannot be empty

```
{"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Path cannot be empty at C:\\laragon\\www\\nextdrive_web\\vendor\\nyholm\\psr7\\src\\Factory\\Psr17Factory.php:41)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\laragon\\www\\nextdrive_web\\vendor\\symfony\\psr-http-message-bridge\\Factory\\PsrHttpFactory.php(118): Nyholm\\Psr7\\Factory\\Psr17Factory->createStreamFromFile('')
#1 C:\\laragon\\www\\nextdrive_web\\vendor\\symfony\\psr-http-message-bridge\\Factory\\PsrHttpFactory.php(100): Symfony\\Bridge\\PsrHttpMessage\\Factory\\PsrHttpFactory->createUploadedFile(Object(Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\File\\UploadedFile))
#2 C:\\laragon\\www\\nextdrive_web\\vendor\\symfony\\psr-http-message-bridge\\Factory\\PsrHttpFactory.php(72): Symfony\\Bridge\\PsrHttpMessage\\Factory\\PsrHttpFactory->getFiles(Array)
#3 C:\\laragon\\www\\nextdrive_web\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RoutingServiceProvider.php(139): Symfony\\Bridge\\PsrHttpMessage\\Factory\\PsrHttpFactory->createRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#4 C:\\laragon\\www\\nextdrive_web\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(873): Illuminate\\Routing\\RoutingServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array)
#5 C:\\laragon\\www\\nextdrive_web\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(758): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure))
```

Comment: Can you post the code(s) that triggers the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is normally permission issue, to overcome this , first check for the directory if it exists .

```
$thumbnailPath = storage_path("your_path");
if (!file_exists($thumbnailPath)) {
     mkdir($thumbnailPath, 0777, true);
  }
```